# The error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, android-activity

I add Version detection in the entrance of activity. And add the following code in onCreate method.

```
new Thread(){
         public void run(){
         try{
         checkToUpdate();
         }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
         }
            }.run();
```

Now it has a new thread. But why it has the error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in android 4.0?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post your manifest, cause it seems like you are missing some permissions?

Comment: @Bhaskar Please see my answer it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be ***start()*** instead of ***run()***

```
new Thread(){
         public void run()
         {
            try{
            checkToUpdate();
         }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
         }
            }.start();
```

And may be you have not added internet permission in manifest file

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `start()` method.

The `run()` method is called on the current thread, while the `start()` method creates a new thread and calls the `run()` method on the newly created thread.

In earlier Android versions, if you ran a long operation on the main (UI) thread, you didn't get the exception immediately, only after Dalvik detected that the application is not responsive for a few seconds. Now, an exception is thrown if you try to perform network communication on the main thread, to let you find those issues easily at development time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use `AsyncTask` or `Handler with Thread` you can't anymore use the Main thread to do Network Processes after `HONEY COMB`

Answer (score 0):

Long running tasks and network operations shoudn't be put on onCreate() method because there will a small time allocated to complete the onCreate() method (probably 4 sec or less), You move it to onResume() method, and if possible put it in AsyncTask.